# How to update global state that uses a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, state, state-management

**Question**

I'm working on a web application feature that calculates the heat insulation factor for a specific area. You can check out the [live Codesandbox example here](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/cloudmako09/btu-calc/main?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FinsulFactor%2FinsulFactor.tsx%3A1%2C1&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnd9z7qu0007356mdmjohkm1%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnd9z7qt0003356m9a2pbp96%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnd9z7qt0005356m2fhlmjgh%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnd9z7qt0006356m59g30n2b%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B60%252C40%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clnd9z7qt0003356m9a2pbp96%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnd9z7qt0003356m9a2pbp96%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clnkorws6008n356mga9mc0mi%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FuseTempDiffFactorStore.tsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnkorws6008n356mga9mc0mi%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252FtempDiffFactor%252FtempDiffFactor.tsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnkortw1005g356m6mennz14%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clnd9z7qt0006356m59g30n2b%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnd9z7qt0006356m59g30n2b%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnd9znzc00as356m67b5lk67%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clnd9znzc00as356m67b5lk67%2522%257D%252C%2522clnd9z7qt0005356m2fhlmjgh%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnd9z7qt0005356m2fhlmjgh%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clnd9zl8i0099356mh5wsd67h%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnd9z7qt0004356mqlenn64j%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clnkkqcc90002e5d9gmufgl9v%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnd9zl8i0099356mh5wsd67h%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) (it's the 2nd yellow area).

The issue I'm facing is that when a user selects values for outdoor and indoor temperatures, the Difference properly updates from the Zustand store. However, the Temperature Difference Factor result, which is `difference / 24`, does not update. I've written `setResult` to so in the code below.

I can see in the console logs that the Temperature Difference Factor's state is not updating, even though I have it setup. I might be doing something wrong though, as it's state should be auto-updating on the fly. How can I fix this?

**Zustand Global Store:**

```
const useTempDiffFactorStore = create<useTempDiffFactor>(
  zukeeper((set: any, get: any) => ({
    outdoorTemp: 0,
    indoorTemp: 0,
    difference: 0,
    result: 0,
    setOutdoorTemp: (value: any) =>
      set({ outdoorTemp: value, difference: value - get().indoorTemp }),
    setIndoorTemp: (value: any) =>
      set({ indoorTemp: value, difference: value - get().outdoorTemp }),
    setDifference: (value: any) =>
      set({ difference: value - get().outdoorTemp - get().indoorTemp }),
    setResult: () => { // this is the function that's not working
      const result = get().difference / 24;
      set({ result: result });
      console.log("Setting result:", result);
    },
  }))
);

export default useTempDiffFactorStore;
```

**Temperature Difference Factor component:**

```
export const TempDiffFactor = () => {
  const {
    outdoorTemp,
    indoorTemp,
    difference,
    result,
    setOutdoorTemp,
    setIndoorTemp,
  } = useTempDiffFactorStore();

  ...

  console.log("Result", result);

  return (
    <>
      <section className="temp-diff-factor">
        ...
          <Col lg="3" className="d-flex align-items-center">
            <Result
              heading="Temperature Difference Factor"
              number={result} // passing it in here
            />
          </Col>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};
```